# How to have a counter for a binary search in C++?

Tags: c++, counter, binary-search

I am not sure how to have a counter for a binary search to determine how many comparisons was made before finding the target number that is inputted. Do I add a counter near the end of the binary search?

```
void search (int arr[])
{
int target;

int first = 0,
    last = MAX - 1,
    mid,
    position = -1;
int row = 2;
    bool found = false;

cout << "Enter in target number to search for: ";
cin >> target;

while (!found && first <= last)
{
    mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if (avg[row][mid] == target)
    {
        cout << "found at index " << mid << endl;
        found = true;
    }
    else if (avg[row][mid] > target)
        last = mid - 1;
    else
        first = mid + 1;
}
if (!found)
    cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

Comment: add a counter in the while loop or in every if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
int counter = 0;                  // Number of comparisons before target is found
while (!found && first <= last)
{
    mid = (first + last) / 2;
    counter = counter + 1;        // Changes to be made

    ... Rest of the code

    else
        first = mid + 1;
}
```

**OR**

```
int counter = 0;                  // Number of comparison before target is found
while (!found && first <= last)
{
    mid = (first + last) / 2;

    if (avg[row][mid] == target)
    {
        cout << "found at index " << mid << endl;
        found = true;
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
    else if (avg[row][mid] > target) 
    {
        last = mid - 1;
        counter = counter + 1;      // Changes to be made
    }
    else 
    {
        first = mid + 1;
        counter = counter + 1;      // Changes to be made
    }    
}
```

Here, counter is declared  before the while loop and then is incremented by one each time till the result is found.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a counter variable before the while loop, and increment it at the end of the while loop, after the last else (not in the else clause)

Answer (score 0):

int count=0;
...rest of code
    else if (avg[row][mid] > target)
        last = mid - 1;
        count++

```
else
    first = mid + 1;
    count++;
```

}
if (!found)
    cout << "Not found\n";
    cout<<"counter="<